# Operations on os.path.getctime

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp

I am reading the following JSON:

```
 {
 "Age": 15,
 "startTime": {
     "date": "06/15/2021",
     "time": "4:04 pm",
     "utcTimestamp": 1623765862
 },...
```

with

```
 data=json.load(self.fName)  
 Dict['StartDate'] = data['startTime']['date']
 Dict['StartTime'] = data['startTime']['time']
```

I also created a variable to track the file creation time:

```
 fileCreationTime= datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(fname)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I am trying to find the amount of time between the time the json file was created and the "StartTime" in the json file.
I tried a few things including:

```
daysToUpload = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(fname)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') - Dict['StartDate']
```

But that did not work. (unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str').
Maybe I can use the UPC time but

```
>>os.path.getctime(fname)
>>1635377313.0170193
```

I'm not sure how to relate that the UTC.

I'd like:

```
timeToUpload = fileCreationDate - TimeSpecifiedInJsonFile
```

This is Python 3.x running on Windows.

Comment: you should covert both your ctime and your dict start time to date time objects, then you can subtract one from the other and get a time delta object

Comment: @ChrisDoyle since the OP already has UNIX time stamps, I think it would be easier to work with those - subtracting the two gives delta time in seconds, which can then be used to create a timedelta object if needed.

Answer (score 1):

To get the time difference, you can simply use utc_timestamp itself without converting it to datetime format as follows:

```
fileCreationDate = int(os.path.getctime(fname)) # utc timestamp
TimeSpecifiedInJsonFile = int(data['startTime']['utcTimestamp']) # utc timestamp
timeToUpload = fileCreationDate - TimeSpecifiedInJsonFile
print(timeToUpload)  # will be print a time difference (seconds)
```